# Listening UI Events on MainThread(UI Thread) and what view that triggers the event

Tags: android, ui-thread, listen, uievent

is there anyway to listen on UIevents such as button click on main/ui thread? without interacting directly on each UI's callbacks(e.g onClickListener) ?

I just want to listen to any thing it fires from ui events, I've been digging around but I only find something that **posts** message **to** the ui thread from another thread, what I want is just **listen** to UI thread when for example a button is clicked,

```
findViewById(R.id.button_1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // some button click stuffs here
        }
    });

    // this is where I want to listen from ui events (e.g click),
    // and determine what type of view that triggered that event
    // or how to get the actual view object that triggered it
```

I'm assuming that this could already be asked(It will be fine if this will be marked as duplicate, but please provide a related post if there is/are), every time I try to search for something like "listen to main thread", I cant find something like what exactly I need, Any help would be greatly appreciated, or any related links.

Edit:  the current situation is, there is no way for me to interact with an existing code, so I'm trying to find a way to listen on those UI events without touching the actual codes(via separate module/library), I dont know if this is possible to achieve though

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what is your purpose ?

Comment: sorry I just edited my question, regarding with my goal on why I need to  do it,

Answer (score 0):

i think there is no direct way to do that, if you want to handle it outside, use the **Handler**

Comment: yes I've been reading things about handler, Looper, but all codes i've been seeing is that theres something that needs to kick(handler.post) so an event will trigger , its always a two-way interaction, I just need a one-way, a pseudo explanation might be like this (attach a handler on the ui thread, then just listen to what ever or what messages the ui thread fires)